# What things can `la` mark in Toki Pona?

Tags: toki-pona

I was under the impression, until recently, the `la` in Toki Pona is a topic marker of sorts similar to the Japanese topic marker `wa` but used less frequently since Toki Pona is not topic-prominent.

In particular, I thought that `la`

1. Requires the noun phrase it marks to appear at the beginning of the clause.
2. Does not give the noun phrase it marks a particular semantic role.

However, [a section about it on Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Toki_Pona/Grammatical_categories) suggests that its usage is much more limited.

> *Time-Manner-Place Schema*
>
> Time comes first in a *la* fragment, manner is a modifier to the main verb, and place is always last in a *lon* prepositional phrase.
>
> `Time la S li V Manner lon Place`

What is `la` in Toki Pona? What are the limits on the noun phrases `la` can mark and the roles they can have in the clause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The particle `la` in Toki Pona is used mainly for two scenarios.

**The first scenario** is for the `If/when something, then that` condition. The `la` particle is placed in the second half of a sentence. Some examples:

- mi lape lili, la mi pilin ike (*If I sleep a little, then I feel bad*
  or *When I sleep a little, I feel bad*)
- sina moku e telo mute, la sina anpa e telo mute lon tenpo lili (*If
  you drink much water/liquid, you are going to pee much in a short time*)

**The second scenario** is for the context, like time, possibilities, or even non yes/no questions. The `la` particle is placed in the first half of a sentence. Some examples:

- tenpo pimeja ni la, mi lukin e lipu sin (*I am going to read the new book tonight*)
- tenpo suno pini lili la, mi kute mute e kalama musi (*Yesterday I listened to much music*)
- ken la, pilin pi meli lili li pilin ike (*Maybe the girl's sad* —literally, "Maybe the heart of the girl feels bad")
- tan seme la, kulupu pi jan lili sona li tawa ala tomo sona? (*Why are the scholars not going to the school?*)

Hope this helps!

Comment: generally 'pee' is translated as 'pana e telo jelo'. "sina moku e telo mute, la sina pana e telo jelo pi mute lon tenpo lili"